# Network bridge disconnects and reconnects to Xbox 360

Tags: 11.10, network-bridge, xbox-360

I am trying to setup a network bridge to my xbox 360, but the wired connection notifies me that it is connected,5 seconds later it notifies me it disconnected, and it keeps in a cycle until I disconnect the Ethernet cable.

My xbox notifies my that it can't obtain an IP address, and that there is no connection. All of this worked perfect in ubuntu 11.04, is there something different in 11.10? Or am I choosing the wrong settings?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the auto connect settings under the ipv4/6 settings under your ethernet connection in network manager, if its set to "connect automatically" it will just keep connecting and disconnecting.

your other issue after you change that will be that your ethernet connection may say "connected" and then "disconnected" but not go back to connected. to fix this you need to set your dhcp stuff up properly (depending on what your setup is) if its anything like mine (usb wireless broadband modem, xbox connected via ethernet cable; then follow this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server

one thing though with the above tutorial is you will needlessly need to replace the code in the first file, i dont know why but i replaced it with the last section of code.

im using ubuntu 11.10

give that a go.